# MySQL - adding constraint once adds it twice with diffent case

Tags: mysql, constraints, case-sensitive, duplication

I have this weird behaviour when I add a constraint to a MySQL table:

```
[...] add constraint qrtz_blob_triggers_ibfk_1 foreign key [...]
```

Now SHOW CREATE TABLE shows the constraint twice:

```
CONSTRAINT `qrtz_blob_triggers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY [...]
CONSTRAINT `QRTZ_BLOB_TRIGGERS_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY [...]
```

Here is the complete session:

```
mysql> DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS my_test; CREATE DATABASE my_test default character set utf8 collate utf8_bin;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.07 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> use my_test;
Database changed
mysql> 
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `QRTZ_TRIGGERS`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> CREATE TABLE `QRTZ_TRIGGERS` (
       `TRIGGER_NAME` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
       `TRIGGER_GROUP` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (`TRIGGER_NAME`,`TRIGGER_GROUP`)
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `QRTZ_BLOB_TRIGGERS`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> create table `QRTZ_BLOB_TRIGGERS` (`TRIGGER_NAME` varchar(80) not null, `TRIGGER_GROUP` varchar(80) not null, `BLOB_DATA` longblob, primary key (`TRIGGER_NAME`, `TRIGGER_GROUP`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> alter table `QRTZ_BLOB_TRIGGERS`  add index qrtz_blob_triggers_ibfk_1 (`TRIGGER_NAME`, `TRIGGER_GROUP`), add constraint qrtz_blob_triggers_ibfk_1 foreign key (`TRIGGER_NAME`, `TRIGGER_GROUP`) references `QRTZ_TRIGGERS` (`TRIGGER_NAME`, `TRIGGER_GROUP`) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.18 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> 
mysql> show create table QRTZ_BLOB_TRIGGERS \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: QRTZ_BLOB_TRIGGERS
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `QRTZ_BLOB_TRIGGERS` (
  `TRIGGER_NAME` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `TRIGGER_GROUP` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `BLOB_DATA` longblob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TRIGGER_NAME`,`TRIGGER_GROUP`),
  KEY `qrtz_blob_triggers_ibfk_1` (`TRIGGER_NAME`,`TRIGGER_GROUP`),
  CONSTRAINT `qrtz_blob_triggers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`TRIGGER_NAME`, `TRIGGER_GROUP`) REFERENCES `QRTZ_TRIGGERS` (`TRIGGER_NAME`, `TRIGGER_GROUP`),
  CONSTRAINT `QRTZ_BLOB_TRIGGERS_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`TRIGGER_NAME`, `TRIGGER_GROUP`) REFERENCES `QRTZ_TRIGGERS` (`TRIGGER_NAME`, `TRIGGER_GROUP`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Using

```
[...] add constraint QRTZ_BLOB_TRIGGERS_ibfk_1 foreign key [...]
```

works fine.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with MySQL 5.5:

```
mysql-server-5.5     5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
```

Does anyone have a clue what's going on there?

Comment: I tired it ... and didn't observe the same behavior ?!?

Comment: Maybe something in relation with [`lower_case_table_names`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names) ?

Comment: Maybe you added it twice? Drop it using both names.

Comment: I have lower_case_table_names=0 as suggested by the MySQL manual: "Use lower_case_table_names=0 on Unix and [...]"

Comment: Maybe are you on a case-insensitive file system? (I'm not even sure if *this* would impact somehow constrain identifiers... :°)

Comment: As use can see in the session I dropped the database and the tables. I issued only one alter table statement. :(

Comment: Ubuntu with ext4 file system. Definitely not case-insensitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69693), fixed in the [upcoming release](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-2.html):

> InnoDB would rename a user-defined foreign key constraint containing the string “*ibfk*” in its name, resulting in a duplicate constraint."

The bug report advises a fix in versions 5.1.72, 5.5.32, 5.6.14, 5.7.2, but I suspect a typo for the 5.5 branch. Considering the release dates, I would expect the fix in v5.5.**34**.